# Flask functional pytest testing of routes with database rollback

Tags: python, flask, neo4j, pytest

I'm trying to use `pytest` to write functional tests for a Flask application which interfaces with a Neo4j graph database via the [Neo4j driver](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-python-driver).

The toy example using the [Movie Database](https://neo4j.com/developer/movie-database/) is outlined below using a route which deletes a record from the database. For testing purposes I would like to wrap the session in a transaction which would be rolled-back rather than committed.

The application has routes which runs Cypher statements within an auto-commit transaction via, `session.run(...)`, however I can circumvent this logic during testing by enforcing the use of a transaction prior to request,

```py
session.begin_transaction()
...
session.rollback_transaction()
```

My question is I'm unsure how to leverage this pattern using `pytest`. Do I have to somehow bind the database to the client? Also is there a fixture I can use which will ensure that every test leveraging the client will be wrapped in a transaction which can be rolled back?

myapp/app.py:

```
from flask import _app_ctx_stack, Flask, Response
from flask_restplus import Api, Resource
from neo4j.v1 import GraphDatabase


class FlaskGraphDatabase(object):
    def __init__(self, app=None):
        self.app = app

        if app is not None:
            self.init_app(app)

    def init_app(self, app):
        @app.teardown_appcontext
        def teardown(exception):
            ctx = _app_ctx_stack.top

            if hasattr(ctx, 'neo4j_session'):
                ctx.neo4j_session.close()

            if hasattr(ctx, 'neo4j_driver'):
                ctx.neo4j_driver.close()

    @property
    def driver(self):
        ctx = _app_ctx_stack.top

        if ctx is not None:
            if not hasattr(ctx, 'neo4j_driver'):
                ctx.neo4j_driver = GraphDatabase.driver('bolt://localhost:7687')

            return ctx.neo4j_driver

    @property
    def session(self):
        ctx = _app_ctx_stack.top

        if ctx is not None:
            if not hasattr(ctx, 'neo4j_session'):
                ctx.neo4j_session = self.driver.session()

            return ctx.neo4j_session


api = Api()
gdb = FlaskGraphDatabase()


@api.route('/<source>/acted_in/<target>')
class Friend(Resource):
    def delete(self, source, target):
        statement = """
            MATCH (s:Person)-[r:ACTED_IN]->(t:Movie)
            WHERE s.name = {source} AND t.title = {target}
            DELETE r
        """

        cursor = gdb.session.run(statement, source=source, target=target)
        status = 204 if cursor.summary().counters.contains_updates else 404
        return Response(status=status)


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    gdb.init_app(app)
    api.init_app(app)
    return app


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = create_app()
    app.run()
```

tests/conftest.py:

```
import pytest

from myapp.app import create_app


@pytest.yield_fixture(scope='session')
def app():
    yield create_app()

@pytest.yield_fixture(scope='session')
def client(app):
    with app.test_client() as client:
        yield client
```

tests/test_routes.py:

```
def test_delete(client):
    res = client.delete('/Keanu Reeves/acted_in/The Matrix')
    assert res.status_code == 204
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use a fixture to achieve this : add an autouse fixture with session scope in your conftest.py which will start a transaction at the begining of the test session and roll it back at the end.

tests/conftest.py:

```py
from neomodel import db


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope="session")
def setup_neo_test_db():
    print("Initializing db transaction")
    db.begin()
    yield
    print("Rolling back")
    db.rollback()
```